# error for absolute import in react typescript app

Tags: reactjs, typescript

this below error show when import module
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./src/App.tsx 5:0-33
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'routes' in 'F:\Tamrinat\Porfolio\microsite\microsite-admin\src'
Did you mean './routes'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, F:\Tamrinat\Porfolio\microsite\microsite-admin\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts", "./**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "extends": "./base-tsconfig.json"
}`

base-tsconfi.json:
`{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./src",
      "paths": {
        "src/*": ["./src/*"]
      }
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "microsite-admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^5.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.24",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "antd": "^5.4.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.9",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "zustand": "^4.3.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26"
  }
}
```

why it do not recognize module?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following configuration to tsconfig.json file.

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@/*": ["src/*"]
}
```